# How can the area of a sector of a circle be equal to (1/2).(OA.OA).theta

Tags: trigonometry

How can the area of a sector of a circle be equal to  (1/2).(OA.OA).theta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Area of a sector is proportional to the angle it subtends at the centre. If you know the area of the complete circle (a sector that subtends angle $2 \pi$) is $\pi r^2$, then the area of a sector that subtends angle $\theta$ is

$$ =  \pi r^2 \times   \dfrac{\theta}{2\pi}= \dfrac{r^2 \theta}{2}$$